# Electron App Not Working With `ffi-napi` Module

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, native, ffi

I have the following electron code,

```
//main.js
const e = require("electron");
const ffi = require("ffi-napi");

const user32 = new ffi.Library("user32", {
  GetKeyState: ["short", ["int32"]],
});

console.log(user32.GetKeyState(0x06) < 0);

function createWindow() {
  let win = new e.BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });
  win.loadFile("index.html");
}

e.app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
```

My main objective is to access windows.h functions inside an electron application. `ffi-node` seems to be working fine as a separate node application.

However, when I embed it into an electron app and run `electron main.js` it looks like it is running for few seconds, then it quits. No error code no nothing. When I try to remove the line `const ffi = require("ffi-napi");` and corresponding method call, it seems to be working properly. I've also tried rebuilding the application via `electron-builder install-app-deps` and it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to fix the issue by changing code to this.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const ffi = require("ffi-napi");

const user32 = new ffi.Library("user32", {
  GetKeyState: ["short", ["int32"]],
});

console.log(user32.GetKeyState(0x06) < 0);

var win;

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });
  win.loadFile("index.html");
}
app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

And `npm install electron -g` followed by `npm link electron`